# How to subtract months in dates?

Tags: javascript

I have this dates function:

```
var isAnnual;
var setupDate="05/09/2016"
var currDate = new Date();//today
```

I need to check if subtraction of the **months** in dates above is equal to zero.

Any idea what is the best way to implement it?

Comment: Did you search? [`[javascript] date month difference`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+date+month+difference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fetch the month from date and subtract it

> Note: month starts from 0 i.e. Jan -0 , Dec -11

```
var s= new Date("05/09/2016");
var currDate = new Date();
console.log(s.getMonth()-currDate.getMonth());
```

Comment: This will work only if both dates are during the same year. This will think that e.g. there's no difference between 5/9/2016 and 5/9/1999.

Comment: yes, you are right, in that case you can subtract the year too then convert year to months,

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is not asked very accurate, because it does not really desribe what you want, e.g. there are at least these options:

1.) You want to compare the current Month with the month of the given date, which is by the way also not accurate formatted.
Pseudocode for that:

```
givenDate := "05/09/2016";
currentDate := determineCurrentDate();

givenMonth := extractMonthFromDateString(givenDate);
currentMonth := extractMonthFromDate(currentDate);

return givenMonth = currentMonth;
```

2.) You want to determine if the currentDate is inside the month of the given Date
Pseudocode for that:

```
givenDate := "05/09/2016";
currentDate := determineCurrentDate();

givenMonth := extractMonthFromDateString(givenDate);
currentMonth := extractMonthFromDate(currentDate);
givenYear := extractYearFromDateString(givenDate);
currentYear := extractYearFromDate(currentDate);

return givenMonth = currentMonth AND givenYear = currentYear;
```

A JS based solution for the first approach is the following one, the second option is really easy to build out of this one:

```
var setupDate = "05/09/2016"; // Format: dd/mm/yyyy
var currDate = new Date();
var monthsEqual = currDate.getMonth() == setupDate.replace(
        /(\d\d)\/(\d\d)\/(\d{4})/, // regex for dd/mm/yyyy
        function(date, day, month, year){ // regard the order of the params
            return new Date(year, parseInt(month)-1, parseInt(day)).getMonth();
        });
```

console.log(monthsEqual);